# React Native version check

Tags: react-native, npm, version, react-native-cli

I wanted to check the version of the react native I was using in my project when I used the command from my root folder :

```
D:\Reactnative\Albums>npm view react-native version
0.56.0
```

The version was 0.56.0 which is not the version I have installed, but on:

```
D:\Reactnative\Albums>react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.4
```

The version mentioned here is 0.55.4, which is correct.
So why this conflict?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> npm view react-native version

You can check the latest version of react native. You can run it under the root of your project or everywhere. Of course, you will need internet connection to check latest version.

> react-native -v

If you run under the root of project, it will return the version of two npm packages, **react-native-cli** and r**eact-native**. Those versions are using in your project.

Comment: I'm "npm view react-native version" command learned now and this command presented correct result for me. Thanks.

Comment: @muratoner this was the actual answer. thank you. there is no 'react-native' command.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to clarify Aung's answer:

`npm view react-native version` checks globally while `react-native -v` ran inside project's root folder checks version of the app itself.

Comment: so how come when I go into my project root and enter 'react-native -v" if get command not found?

Answer (score 0):

Macbook M1 Chip

> npm view react-native version